# SQL: how to distinguish between 2 rows and selecting one row when selecting a column that is the one corresponding to max on another column

Tags: sql

I'm using postgres. I have a table called Books
with columns:

| id | title | category | publish_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | t1 | c1 | 12.03.2020 |
| id2 | t2 | c1 | 12.03.2022 |

I want to select the category of the most recent publication book. In this ex the output should be the row with id2. My query works but only when the category is distinct.

````
select title, category, publish_date
from books b
              JOIN
              (SELECT MAX(publish_date) AS maxPD FROM books b2 GROUP BY category) max
              ON b.publish_date = max.maxPD
              where add.id = 'id2'
                  and category in ('c1', 'c2')
                  ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there would be only one most recent publication book, on Postgres we can use a limit query:

```sql
SELECT title, category, publish_date
FROM books
ORDER BY publish_date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

You may try the following version as well, which might work with HQL:

```sql
SELECT title, category, publish_date
FROM books
WHERE publish_date = (SELECT MAX(publish_date) FROM books);
```

Comment: Biegeleisenthat would work but I'm using hql and this part is a subquery inside of a select so I cannot use limit

Comment: @anonimos Try the second version in my updated answer.